# Booting Linux from USB

Tags: 14.04, boot, 13.04, usb

I'm trying to boot Linux from USB to run an application. When I boot Live Linux, the data is gone and it is new again when I reboot the OS. I want to retain the data and run the application and also use it as normal USB.

Comment: Search for "persistence" as this how the feature you want is called: Booting a live system from USB, but storing session data to the same volume.

Comment: Does just adding `persistent` to the boot line work? Or do you have to create the `casper-rw` file first?

Comment: @ophouddin22 Did my answer resolve it for you? If so, [please click the check-mark to mark it as the answer](http://askubuntu.com/help/accepted-answer). That way, people who come in the future can easily see what the solution is!

Answer (score 1):

Even if you do decide to follow these instructions, I suggest you read the [LiveUsbPendrivePersistent](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/LiveUsbPendrivePersistent) wiki page. Reading Wiki pages is a great way to learn and you'll know more about what you're doing - rather than just following steps blindly.

---

Normally, I'd suggest that you use the Startup Disk Creator in Ubuntu to do this - it has a really simple option:

[image]

that allows you to add MB of space to keep stored in reserved extra space. However, there is a bug with installing the bootloader:

[image]

at least for me.

So, I'd suggest you use Unetbootin. It's not quite as polished, but it does the exact same job and has the exact same store in reserve functionality. It's what I use when creating LiveUSBs and has yet to fail me.

It's in the default repositories, so you can install it via `sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install unetbootin`.

Once it's installed, open up the dash (<kbd>Super</kbd> key - aka Windows key) and open up unetbootin - you'll have to search for it. It'll require the sudo password, just a heads up. You'd need sudo access just to install the app, so that's no problem.

[image]

Once unetbootin starts, you'll want to change the radio button from selecting `Distribution` (default choice) to selecting `Diskimage` and then click the <kbd>...</kbd> button. You can then select the ISO and it will show up in the text box.

Once you've selected the ISO you want, make sure the type is set to `USB drive` and that it's targeting the correct USB drive. If you've got USB backup media or other USB sticks attached to your computer, you may want to consider disconnecting them for a bit - just to be safe and sure you don't accidentally overwrite some important data.

Now, to add the persistence of data, simply change the `Space used to preserve files across reboots (Ubuntu only)` value. This should create a file-system on the USB stick, along with the ISO contents, that will store your information across reboots!

[image]

Note, that if you use Unetbootin to create the LiveUSB, you'll have to specify the space in **MB** (MegaBytes) not GB (Gigabytes). A simple way to convert this is just punch into a calculator `numberOfGigabytes * 1024`. That will provide you with the correct amount of space in MB terms (as there are 1024 MB in a GB.)

Comment: Nice answer. Oddly enough I have intermittent problems with both programs on multiple machines. No rhyme or reason to it.

Comment: @ScottGoodgame Yeah, computers can be finicky and weird sometimes.

Comment: Seems like every live USB creating program has problems sometimes, with some ISO's, or under some types of moons... I switched to the GRUB multiboot ISO method, if GRUB works then so does the USB (maybe some ISO's won't work, but every Debian-based one I've tried does, Arch & Fedora do too I *think* - But persistence would be a more manual setup